# Are the available fonts on every iPhone and iPad always the same?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, fonts

Looking at [this list](http://iosfonts.com/), is it guaranteed that a font, say "Baskerville SemiBold", is available on all iPads and iPhones with iOS-version >= 5.0?

I mean regardless of in which country the device was sold in or what the specific hardware-model is, and so forth?

I want to use these fonts in my app and wonder if I should program checks if those fonts are indeed available on the host-OS or if I can safely assume their presence.

Comment: Not sure about that. But you can always include your custom font in your application and use that across the screen. That way you can confirm that this font is used everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's guaranteed that you'll have the **Baskerville SemiBold** on all iOS devices running iOS 5.0 and above. Use the font with confidence!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the official apple documentation, iosfonts website is a good resource for available fonts on different OS verions

http://iosfonts.com/